# how to retrive data from odt xml file in python?

Tags: python

I am successfully retreving the odt xml file in python but I have no idea how to pull xml file data?

Any techniques are there for pulling the odt xml file data.

Here my code for extracting odt xml file

```
#!/usr/lib/python2.7

import sys, zipfile

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "input.odt & output.xml"
    sys.exit(0)

content=""
myfile = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1])
listoffiles = myfile.infolist()
for s in listoffiles:
    if s.orig_filename == 'content.xml':
        fd = open(sys.argv[2],'w')
        content = myfile.read(s.orig_filename)
        fd.write(content)
        fd.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

`Any techniques are there for pulling the odt xml file data.` I'm assuming you're curious about parsing this xml file's contents. If that is the case, I recommend [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). BS is intended for html parsing, but can be altered to accept xml data:

BS4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = Beautifulsoup(<xml file contents>, 'xml')
```

BeautifulSoup 3:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(<xml file contents>)
```

From here you can parse the data according to the docs (linked above).